# React Native: Strange warnings on "overriding gradient" - any explanation?

Tags: react-native, tensorflow.js

I just managed to load a local TensorflowJS model into my React Native application. It works very well! But I got these warnings - can someone explain/a solution to dismiss them? The only way was to remove the imported Tensorflow libraries ((@tensorflow/tfjs and @tensorflow/tfjs-react-native) which is of course not an option. They are all related to overriding specific gradients:

Overriding the gradient for 'Max'

- node_modules/expo/build/environment/muteWarnings.fx.js:18:23 in warn
- node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tf-core.node.js:420:8 in registerGradient
- node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tf-core.node.js:11422:8 in
- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:322:6 in loadModuleImplementation

- http://127.0.0.1:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:181906:29 in

- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:322:6 in loadModuleImplementation

- http://127.0.0.1:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:144444:47 in

- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:322:6 in loadModuleImplementation

- http://127.0.0.1:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:125429:58 in

- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:322:6 in loadModuleImplementation

- http://127.0.0.1:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:125221:55 in

- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:322:6 in loadModuleImplementation
- node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js:3:0 in
- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:322:6 in loadModuleImplementation
- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:201:45 in guardedLoadModule

- http://127.0.0.1:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:299355:4 in global code

Overriding the gradient for 'OneHot'

- node_modules/expo/build/environment/muteWarnings.fx.js:18:23 in warn
- node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tf-core.node.js:420:8 in registerGradient
- node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tf-core.node.js:11422:8 in
- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:322:6 in loadModuleImplementation

- http://127.0.0.1:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:181906:29 in

- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:322:6 in loadModuleImplementation

- http://127.0.0.1:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:144444:47 in

- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:322:6 in loadModuleImplementation

- http://127.0.0.1:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:125429:58 in

- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:322:6 in loadModuleImplementation

- http://127.0.0.1:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:125221:55 in

- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:322:6 in loadModuleImplementation
- node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js:3:0 in
- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:322:6 in loadModuleImplementation
- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:201:45 in guardedLoadModule

- http://127.0.0.1:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:299355:4 in global code

Overriding the gradient for 'PadV2'

- node_modules/expo/build/environment/muteWarnings.fx.js:18:23 in warn
- node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tf-core.node.js:420:8 in registerGradient
- node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tf-core.node.js:11422:8 in
- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:322:6 in loadModuleImplementation

- http://127.0.0.1:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:181906:29 in

- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:322:6 in loadModuleImplementation

- http://127.0.0.1:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:144444:47 in

- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:322:6 in loadModuleImplementation

- http://127.0.0.1:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:125429:58 in

- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:322:6 in loadModuleImplementation

- http://127.0.0.1:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:125221:55 in

- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:322:6 in loadModuleImplementation
- node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js:3:0 in
- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:322:6 in loadModuleImplementation
- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:201:45 in guardedLoadModule

- http://127.0.0.1:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:299355:4 in global code

Overriding the gradient for 'SpaceToBatchND'

- node_modules/expo/build/environment/muteWarnings.fx.js:18:23 in warn
- node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tf-core.node.js:420:8 in registerGradient
- node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tf-core.node.js:11422:8 in
- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:322:6 in loadModuleImplementation

- http://127.0.0.1:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:181906:29 in

- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:322:6 in loadModuleImplementation

- http://127.0.0.1:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:144444:47 in

- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:322:6 in loadModuleImplementation

- http://127.0.0.1:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:125429:58 in

- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:322:6 in loadModuleImplementation

- http://127.0.0.1:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:125221:55 in

- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:322:6 in loadModuleImplementation
- node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js:3:0 in
- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:322:6 in loadModuleImplementation
- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:201:45 in guardedLoadModule

- http://127.0.0.1:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:299355:4 in global code

Overriding the gradient for 'SplitV'

- node_modules/expo/build/environment/muteWarnings.fx.js:18:23 in warn
- node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tf-core.node.js:420:8 in registerGradient
- node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tf-core.node.js:11422:8 in
- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:322:6 in loadModuleImplementation

- http://127.0.0.1:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:181906:29 in

- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:322:6 in loadModuleImplementation

- http://127.0.0.1:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:144444:47 in

- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:322:6 in loadModuleImplementation

- http://127.0.0.1:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:125429:58 in

- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:322:6 in loadModuleImplementation

- http://127.0.0.1:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:125221:55 in

- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:322:6 in loadModuleImplementation
- node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js:3:0 in
- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:322:6 in loadModuleImplementation
- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:201:45 in guardedLoadModule

- http://127.0.0.1:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:299355:4 in global code

Finished building JavaScript bundle in 426ms.
Running application on iPhone 11.

Overriding the gradient for 'Max'

- node_modules/expo/build/environment/muteWarnings.fx.js:18:23 in warn
- node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tf-core.node.js:420:8 in registerGradient
- node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tf-core.node.js:11422:8 in
- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:322:6 in loadModuleImplementation

- http://127.0.0.1:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:181521:29 in

- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:322:6 in loadModuleImplementation

- http://127.0.0.1:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:144440:47 in

- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:322:6 in loadModuleImplementation

- http://127.0.0.1:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:125429:58 in

- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:322:6 in loadModuleImplementation

- http://127.0.0.1:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:125221:55 in

- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:322:6 in loadModuleImplementation
- node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js:3:0 in
- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:322:6 in loadModuleImplementation
- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:201:45 in guardedLoadModule

- http://127.0.0.1:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:298956:4 in global code

Overriding the gradient for 'OneHot'

- node_modules/expo/build/environment/muteWarnings.fx.js:18:23 in warn
- node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tf-core.node.js:420:8 in registerGradient
- node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tf-core.node.js:11422:8 in
- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:322:6 in loadModuleImplementation

- http://127.0.0.1:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:181521:29 in

- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:322:6 in loadModuleImplementation

- http://127.0.0.1:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:144440:47 in

- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:322:6 in loadModuleImplementation

- http://127.0.0.1:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:125429:58 in

- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:322:6 in loadModuleImplementation

- http://127.0.0.1:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:125221:55 in

- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:322:6 in loadModuleImplementation
- node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js:3:0 in
- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:322:6 in loadModuleImplementation
- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:201:45 in guardedLoadModule

- http://127.0.0.1:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:298956:4 in global code

Overriding the gradient for 'PadV2'

- node_modules/expo/build/environment/muteWarnings.fx.js:18:23 in warn
- node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tf-core.node.js:420:8 in registerGradient
- node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tf-core.node.js:11422:8 in
- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:322:6 in loadModuleImplementation

- http://127.0.0.1:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:181521:29 in

- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:322:6 in loadModuleImplementation

- http://127.0.0.1:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:144440:47 in

- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:322:6 in loadModuleImplementation

- http://127.0.0.1:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:125429:58 in

- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:322:6 in loadModuleImplementation

- http://127.0.0.1:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:125221:55 in

- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:322:6 in loadModuleImplementation
- node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js:3:0 in
- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:322:6 in loadModuleImplementation
- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:201:45 in guardedLoadModule

- http://127.0.0.1:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:298956:4 in global code

Overriding the gradient for 'SpaceToBatchND'

- node_modules/expo/build/environment/muteWarnings.fx.js:18:23 in warn
- node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tf-core.node.js:420:8 in registerGradient
- node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tf-core.node.js:11422:8 in
- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:322:6 in loadModuleImplementation

- http://127.0.0.1:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:181521:29 in

- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:322:6 in loadModuleImplementation

- http://127.0.0.1:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:144440:47 in

- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:322:6 in loadModuleImplementation

- http://127.0.0.1:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:125429:58 in

- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:322:6 in loadModuleImplementation

- http://127.0.0.1:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:125221:55 in

- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:322:6 in loadModuleImplementation
- node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js:3:0 in
- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:322:6 in loadModuleImplementation
- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:201:45 in guardedLoadModule

- http://127.0.0.1:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:298956:4 in global code

Overriding the gradient for 'SplitV'

- node_modules/expo/build/environment/muteWarnings.fx.js:18:23 in warn
- node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tf-core.node.js:420:8 in registerGradient
- node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tf-core.node.js:11422:8 in
- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:322:6 in loadModuleImplementation

- http://127.0.0.1:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:181521:29 in

- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:322:6 in loadModuleImplementation

- http://127.0.0.1:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:144440:47 in

- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:322:6 in loadModuleImplementation

- http://127.0.0.1:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:125429:58 in

- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:322:6 in loadModuleImplementation

- http://127.0.0.1:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:125221:55 in

- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:322:6 in loadModuleImplementation
- node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js:3:0 in
- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:322:6 in loadModuleImplementation
- node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js:201:45 in guardedLoadModule

- http://127.0.0.1:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:298956:4 in global code